# Silverstripe tumblr-like Post Types

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to create a back-end interface for silverstripe that gives the CMS user the option to choose between a set of Post Types (like tumblr) in Silverstripe3. So they can choose to create a News Post, Video Post, Gallery Post, etc.

I initially started off giving all Posts the necessary fields for each Type and adding an enum field that allowed the user to choose the Post Type. I then used the forTemplate method to set the template dependent upon which Post Type was chosen.

```
class Post extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
       'Title' => 'Varchar(255),
       'Entry' => 'HTMLText',
       'Type'  => 'enum('Video, Photo, Gallery, Music')
    );

    static $many_many = array(
       'Videos' => 'SiteVideo',
       'Photos' => 'SitePhoto,
       'Songs'  => 'SiteMp3'
    );

    public function forTemplate() {
        switch ($this->Type) {
            case 'Video':
                return $this->renderWith('VideoPost');
                break;
            case 'Photo':
                return $this->renderWith('ImagePost');
                break;
            etc...
    }

    function getCMSFields($params=null) {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields($params);        
        ...   
       $videosField = new GridField(
            'Videos',
            'Videos',
            $this->Videos()->sort('SortOrder'),
            $gridFieldConfig
        );
       $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Videos', $photosField);

        $photosField = new GridField(
            'Photos',
            'Photos',
            $this->Photos()->sort('SortOrder'),
            $gridFieldConfig
        );
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Videos', $photosField);

        return $fields;
    } 
}
```

I would rather the user be able to choose the Post Type in the backend and only the appropriate tabs show up. So if you choose Video, only the Video GridField tab would show up. If you choose Photo Type only the Photo's GridField would show.Then I would like to be able to call something like

```
public function PostList() {
    Posts::get()
}
```

and be able to output all PostTypes sorted by date.

Does anyone know how this might be accomplished? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first part can be accomplished using javascript.  Check out [this tutorial](http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2011/inserting-javascript-into-a-dom-popup/)  and  [the docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/javascript) let me know if you have questions on it.

The second part would be trickier but I think you could do something with the page controller.  Include a method that outputs a different template based on the enum value but you would have to set links somewhere.

I managed this with DataObjectManager in 2.4.7 as I had numerous DataObjects and all were included in one page but I'm not sure if that is feasible in SS3.

```
return $this->renderWith(array('CustomTemplate'));
```

This line of code will output the page using a different template.  You need to include it in a method and then call that method when the appropriate link is clicked.

Comment: Thanks MillyMonster. I take a look at all this and let you know if I have any questions. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No problem. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Just as a follow up, what ended up working for my situation was to check for $this->Type (which corresponds to the values of an enum field that lists each Post Type) and show gridfield tabs or remove fields by name according to which Type was chosen. Since all Post Types are still a 'Post' I can use Post::get() in the template to get all Posts.

Comment: Also, to link to each Post individually, I did what MillyMonster mentioned above.